# How to describe a 'nearby' exterior of a compact set, a terminology?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{A}$ is a compact set in $X$. Then how to describe a set of points in $X$ such that it is outside of $\mathcal{A}$ but close to its boundary ? or, a subset of exterior of $\mathcal{A}$ which is 'nearby' $\mathcal{A}$ ?

Is there a well-known terminology for this ?

Comment: What does "close to" even mean if there is no metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a family of neighbourhoods $\{U(x)\}_{x\in\mathcal A}$. If $X$ is a metric space these neighbourhoods can be balls of radius $\epsilon$. This is an open cover of $\mathcal A$. Then take a finite subcover $\{U(x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

The set
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U(x_n)\setminus\mathcal A$$
should work.

Comment: Why bother taking a finite subcover at all? (Why not keep the original cover?) Also, please fix the indexes: $\{U(x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is not finite if $n$ goes up to $\infty$!

Comment: The finite sub-cover provides the "closeness" one might imagine without a metric.

Comment: @Chickenmancer I know, but without any further clarification, you could have all $U(x)=X$, thus I am not sure you gain much in the case there is no metric.

Answer (score 0):

In any metric space $(X,d)$, for nonempty $A\subseteq X$ and $x\in X$ you can define the *distance of $x$ from $A$* as $d(x, A) = \inf_{y\in A} d(x,y)$. If $x\in A$ then $d(x, A)=0$ but the converse does not need to hold (e.g. $A$ is an open ball $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and $x\not\in A$). However, if $A$ is compact, then the infimum in question is always a minimum (because $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ is a continuous function on $A$), thus it is always achieved by some $y\in A$.

Now to your question. You can take the set:

$$\{x\in X: 0\lt d(x, A) \lt\epsilon\}$$

for some $\epsilon\gt 0$. $d(x,A)\gt 0$ guarantees that those elements are not in $A$, $d(x,A)\lt\epsilon$ means that they are (informally) "close" to $A$, and there aren't any points $x\in X\setminus A$ such that $d(x, A)=0$ due to the compactness argument above.